# Chrome not always executing javascript document.write code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this following function that i use to display adobe flash swf on my web pages.
From around a week from now we have found that this code is not always executed on chrome.

Even if the function is called 2 time on a single page, sometime it only execute only once.
When the page is refreshed the function executes without any problem.
I am using the same function throughout my site, an with the function call written exactly the same way.

And the the function does not get executed every time it is called.

I assume that this error may be comming from the document.write code but i'm not sure, can anyone please help me on this.

Kind Regards 
V!nay

```
    function writeSWFCode(movie,var_string , movie_name, width, height, bgcolor,flash_align,flash_menu,flash_scale,flash_wmode,flash_version,flash_hspace,flash_vspace){
//check for domain name... if none, use flash
var HasProtocol=movie.indexOf('http://');
if(HasProtocol==-1){
    movie=UpToTenFlashDomain + movie;
}
//  alert (movie);
if(bgcolor == '' || bgcolor == undefined){
    //Default color is white... WHen the BG color to a movie is a color, the Background   to any print job will be that color too !
    bgcolor = '#FFFFFF';
}
if(flash_version == '' || flash_version == undefined){
    flash_version = '6,0,29,0';
}
if(flash_align == '' || flash_align == undefined){
    flash_align = 'middle';
}
if(flash_menu == '' || flash_menu == undefined){
    flash_menu = 'false';
}
if(flash_hspace == '' || flash_hspace == undefined){
    flash_hspace = '0';
}
if(flash_vspace == '' || flash_vspace == undefined){
    flash_vspace = '0';
}

if(flash_wmode == '' || flash_wmode == undefined){
    flash_wmode_object='';
    flash_wmode_embed='';
}else{
    flash_wmode_object='<PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="'+flash_wmode+'">';
    flash_wmode_embed=' wmode="'+flash_wmode+'" ';
}
if(flash_scale == '' || flash_scale == undefined){
    flash_scale='exactfit';
}

var browserName =navigator.appName;
var flash_code ='';
flash_code = '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" hspace="'+flash_hspace+'" vspace="'+flash_vspace+'" align="'+flash_align+'" id="'+movie_name+'"><param name="movie" value="'+movie+'" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="'+bgcolor+'" /><param name="play" value="true" /><param name="loop" value="true" />'+flash_wmode_object+'<param name="scale" value="'+flash_scale+'" /><param name="menu" value="'+flash_menu+'" /><param name="devicefont" value="false" /><param name="salign" value="" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="FlashVars" value="'+ var_string +'" />';

 if (browserName!="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
 {
flash_code = flash_code + '<object data="'+movie+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" hspace="'+flash_hspace+'" vspace="'+flash_vspace+'" align="'+flash_align+'"><param name="movie" value="'+movie+'" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="'+bgcolor+'" /><param name="play" value="true" /><param name="loop" value="true" />'+flash_wmode_object+'<param name="scale" value="'+flash_scale+'" /><param name="menu" value="'+flash_menu+'" /><param name="devicefont" value="false" /><param name="salign" value="" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="FlashVars" value="'+ var_string +'" />';
}
flash_code = flash_code + '<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><img src="xxx" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a>';
  if (browserName!="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
  {
 flash_code = flash_code +'</object>';
  }
 flash_code = flash_code +'</object>';          

document.write(flash_code);
// alert(flash_code);
}
```

Comment: Can you try with `innerHTML` please to see what will be the result?